# How does iptables treat hostnames?

Tags: iptables

I have a Python script I made to write rules into iptables that prevents IP blocks from accessing port 22 on my server.

After writing these rules, one of the blocks has a hostname of 'localhost/22'. Will iptables treat this as 127.0.0.1 or will it still acknowledge the actual IP address? I don't want to end up getting locked out of my server from this.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  *****/14  anywhere            
DROP       all  --  localhost/22         anywhere            
DROP       all  --  ****/20      anywhere
```

Also, quick question: Why doesn't iptables show the port for each rule? I'm specifying 22 as dport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't have a rule to allow traffic from loopback interface to be sure?

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -m comment --comment "ALLOW loopback interface" -j ACCEPT
```

you can see the IP for "localhost" with

```
iptables -L -v -n
```

Comment: The result of this command puts a rule at the top of my INPUT which says "source: anywhere". Will this make all of my other rules void?

Comment: An IP packet is always processed only by a single rule, as soon as one is true the IP packet is processed. 

1 packet will never processed twice 
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @Chase it will now allow any packet, only from the loopback interface ( option: `-i lo`   )

Comment: Okay, so my malicous IP ranges will still be dropped? And why doesn't iptables show the dport? I've tried the -n parameter and I still don't see the port number

Comment: Example: `iptables -A INPUT -i venet0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m comment --comment "ALLOW ESTABLISHED connections" -j ACCEPT`; `iptables -A INPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 -i venet0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m comment --comment "ALLOW new SSH connections" -j ACCEPT`

it will allow any answers for open connections and new connections from 8.8.8.8 to port 22

Answer (score 3):

`iptables` is a tool for configuring netfilter, and netfilter doesn't handle hostnames.

When you modify rules, `iptables` resolves hostnames to ip's, and when you list rules `iptables` perform a reverse lookup of the ip's (unless you use the `-n` option).

If localhost resolves to anything else then 127.0.0.1 or is the result of a reverse lookup of anything else, you have a pretty strange setup and are probably in for surprises.

Comment: Some of the malicious IP addresses seem to have a hostname of 'localhost'. If I were to scan them in zenmap it would say, "localhost (randomip)". So if iptables sees this 'localhost' that resolves to an external IP it won't drop packets from 127.0.0.1?

Comment: It seems likely that malicious actors would put "localhost" in reverse DNS for their ip's. Yet another reason never to use hostnames when blocking stuff.

Comment: Yes, I wrote a script that blacklists IPs trying to bruteforce my SSH login and it automatically adds them to iptables. Some of these reverse DNS hostnames are localhost. The IP addresses get added to iptables, but I can see their hostname in iptables with 'iptables -L'. This is why I wanted to make sure the hostnames didn't get resolved to 127.0.0.1.